# How would I get my view to update when weather location array is updated?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

In my weather app I have a view model that has an array of weather locations. In the TopBarView I am trying to make it so I search for a weather location and when I click the plus button it appends it to the weatherVM array in the MultiLocationViewModel. when I click the plus it appends it to the array in the multiviewvm but in the MultiLocationView which goes through all of the locations in the array in multilocationvm and displays them in the topbarview it only displays the name but not any of the weather information like the temperature or weather condition which means that the weather data isn't even being retrieved. when I dismiss the sheet though the the weather data is retrieved and displayed in the WeatherHomeView. I was wondering how I would get the MultiLocationView to update when I append a location to the weatherVM array in multiLocationViewModel. I included two models at the end but I don't think that they are as important as the view and view models that included for this problem. Any help would be great!

WeatherApp

'''

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct WeatherApp: App {
@StateObject var weatherVM = WeatherViewViewModel(city: "")
@StateObject var multiLocationVM = MultiLocationViewModel()
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        WeatherHomeView(weatherVM: weatherVM, multiLocationVM: multiLocationVM)
    }
}
}
```

'''

Views

WeatherHomeView

'''

```
import SwiftUI

struct WeatherHomeView: View {
@ObservedObject var weatherVM: WeatherViewViewModel
@ObservedObject var multiLocationVM: MultiLocationViewModel
@State var pageSelection: String = MultiLocationViewModel().weatherVM[0].city

var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
        BottomNavBarView(weatherVM: weatherVM, multiLocationVM: multiLocationVM, pageSelection: $pageSelection)
        
    }
    .safeAreaInset(edge: .top) {
        TopBarView(weatherVM: weatherVM, multiLocationVM: multiLocationVM, pageSelection: $pageSelection)
    }
}
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    WeatherHomeView(weatherVM: WeatherViewViewModel(city: "phoenix"), multiLocationVM: MultiLocationViewModel(), pageSelection: "")
}
}
```

'''

TopBarView

'''

```
import SwiftUI

struct TopBarView: View {
@ObservedObject var weatherVM: WeatherViewViewModel
@ObservedObject var multiLocationVM: MultiLocationViewModel

@State private var searchTerm = ""
@State var showMultiLocaitonView = false
@Binding var pageSelection: String

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        if multiLocationVM.weatherVM.count == 0 {
            
        } else {
            Button(action: {
                showMultiLocaitonView.toggle()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "mappin.circle")
                    .font(.system(size: 24))
            }
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .padding()
            .sheet(isPresented: $showMultiLocaitonView) {
                NavigationView {
                    MultiLocationView(multiLocationVM: multiLocationVM, showParentSheet: $showMultiLocaitonView, pageSelection: $pageSelection)
                        
                        .toolbar {
                            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                                Text("Places")
                                    .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .medium))
                            }
                            ToolbarItem() {
                                TextField("New Location", text: $searchTerm)
                                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 3, leading: 7, bottom: 3, trailing: 7))
                                    .frame(width: 200)
                                    .background(
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.lightGray))
                                    )
                            }
                            ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                                Button(action: {
                                    if searchTerm != "" {
                                        multiLocationVM.appendLocation(location: WeatherViewViewModel(city: searchTerm))
                                        searchTerm = ""
                                        print("temp \(multiLocationVM.weatherVM[3].weather.current.temp)")
                                    }
                                }) {
                                Image(systemName: "plus")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            
            Image(systemName: "location.fill")
            Text(weatherVM.city)
                .font(
                    .custom("sf pro display", size: 24)
                    .weight(.medium)
                )

            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                    .font(.system(size: 24))
            }
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .padding()
        }
    }
    .background(Color("TopBar"))
}
}

struct TopBarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    TopBarView(weatherVM: WeatherViewViewModel(city: ""), multiLocationVM: MultiLocationViewModel(), pageSelection: .constant("Phoenix"))
        .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
}
}
```

'''

MultiLocationView

'''

```
import SwiftUI

struct MultiLocationView: View {

@ObservedObject var multiLocationVM: MultiLocationViewModel
@Binding var showParentSheet: Bool
@Binding var pageSelection: String


var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color("MultiLocationBackground").ignoresSafeArea()
        
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 15) {
                ForEach(multiLocationVM.weatherVM, id: \.self.city) { location in
                    
                    getLocationView(location: location)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            showParentSheet = false
                            pageSelection = location.city
                        }
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                }
            }
            .padding(.top)
        }
    }
}

private func getLocationView(location: WeatherViewViewModel) -> some View {
    
    HStack(alignment: .center) {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
            Text(location.city)
                .font(.system(size: 28, weight: .regular))
            Text(location.conditions != "" ? location.conditions : "Sunny")
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .regular))
        }
        
        Spacer()
        
        Text("\(location.getTempFor(temp: location.weather.current.temp))°")
            .font(.system(size: 40))
        
        Spacer()
            .frame(width: 10)
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
            Text("H: \(location.getTempFor(temp: location.weather.daily[0].temp.max))°")
                .font(.system(size: 24))
            
            Text("L: \(location.getTempFor(temp: location.weather.daily[0].temp.min))°")
                .font(.system(size: 24))
        }
        
    }
    .padding()
    .background(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
            .fill(
                LinearGradient(colors: [Color("MultiLocationWidgetLeft"), Color("MultiLocationWidgetRight")], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
        )
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.5), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)
    )
}
}

struct MultiLocationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    MultiLocationView(multiLocationVM: MultiLocationViewModel(), showParentSheet: .constant(false), pageSelection: .constant(""))
}
}
```

'''

ViewModels

WeatehrViewViewModel

'''

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

final class WeatherViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var weather = WeatherResponse.empty()
@State var timeZone = WeatherResponse.empty().timezone
@Published var city: String {
    didSet {
        getLocation()
    }
}

private lazy var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .full
    return formatter
}()

private lazy var dayFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
    return formatter
}()

private func timeFormatter(timezone: String) -> DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    // formatter.dateFormat = "hh a"
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timezone)
    return formatter
}

init(city: String) {
    self.city = city
    getLocation()
    //print(self.getTempFor(temp: weather.current.temp))
}

var date: String {
    return dateFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(weather.current.dt)))
}

var sunrise: String {
    return timeFormatter(timezone: weather.timezone).string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(weather.current.sunrise)))
}

var sunset: String {
    return timeFormatter(timezone: weather.timezone).string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(weather.current.sunset)))
}

var weatherIcon: String {
    if weather.current.weather.count > 0 {
        return weather.current.weather[0].icon
    }
    return "sun.max.fill"
}

var temperature: String {
    return getTempFor(temp:weather.current.temp)
}

var conditions: String {
    if weather.current.weather.count > 0 {
        return weather.current.weather[0].main
    }
    return ""
}

var windSpeed: String {
    return String(format: "%0.1f", weather.current.wind_speed)
}

var humidity: String {
    return String(format: "%d%%", weather.current.humidity)
}

var rainChances: String {
    return String(format: "%0.0f%%", weather.current.dew_point)
}

func getTimeFor(timestamp: Int) -> String {
    return timeFormatter(timezone: weather.timezone).string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timestamp)))
}

func getDayFor(timestamp: Int) -> String {
    return dayFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timestamp)))
}

func getTempFor(temp: Double) -> String {
    return String(format: "%0.0f", temp)
}

private func getLocation() {
    CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(city, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error: ", error!)
        }
        if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
            self.getWeather(coord: placemark.location!.coordinate)
            //print("Inside getLocation")
        }
    })
}

private func getWeather(coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D?) {
    if let coord = coord {
        let urlString = API.getURLFor(lat: coord.latitude, lon: coord.longitude)
        getWeatherInternal(city: city, for: urlString)
    } else {
        let urlString = API.getURLFor(lat: 37.5485, lon: -121.9886)
        getWeatherInternal(city: city, for: urlString)
    }
}

private func getWeatherInternal(city: String, for urlString: String) {
    NetworkManager<WeatherResponse>.fetch(for: URL(string: urlString)!) { (result) in
        print(urlString)
        switch result {
        case.success(let response):
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.weather = response
            }
            
        case .failure(let err):
            print(err)
        }
    }
}

func getWeatherIconFor(icon: String) -> Image {
    switch icon {
        case "01d":
            return Image(systemName: "sun.max.fill") //"clear_sky_day" case "0ln"
        case "01n":
            return Image(systemName: "moon.fill") //"clear_sky_night"
        case "02d":
            return Image(systemName: "cloud.sun.fill") //"few_clouds_day" case "02n":
        case "02n":
            return Image(systemName: "cloud.moon.fill") //"few_clouds_night" case "03d"
        case "03d":
            return Image(systemName: "cloud.fill") //"scattered_clouds" case "03n"
        case "03n":
            return Image(systemName: "cloud.fill") //"scattered_clouds" case "04d"
        case "04d":
            return Image(systemName: "cloud.fill") //"broken_clouds" case "04n":
        case "04n":
            return Image(systemName: "cloud.fill") //"broken_clouds" case "09d":
        case "09d":
            return Image(systemName: "cloud.drizzle.fill") //"shower_rain" case "09n":
        case "09n":
            return Image(systemName: "cloud.drizzle.fill") //"shower_rain" case "10d":
        case "10d":
            return Image(systemName: "cloud.heavyrain.fill")//"rain_day" case
        case "10n":
            return Image(systemName: "cloud.heavyrain.fill") //"rain_night" case "11d":
        case "11d":
            return Image(systemName: "cloud.bolt.fill") //"thunderstorm_day" case "11n":
        case "11n":
            return Image(systemName: "cloud.bolt.fill") //"thunderstorm_night" case "13d":
        case "13d":
            return Image(systemName: "cloud.snow.fill") //"snow"
        case "13n":
            return Image(systemName: "cloud.snow.fill") //"snow"
        case "50d":
            return Image(systemName: "cloud.fog.fill") //"mist"
        case "50n":
            return Image(systemName: "cloud.fog.fill") //"mist"
        default:
            return Image(systemName: "sun.max.fill")
    }
}
}
```

'''

MultiLocationViewModel

'''

```
import Foundation

class MultiLocationViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var weatherVM: [WeatherViewViewModel] = [WeatherViewViewModel(city: "Phoenix"), WeatherViewViewModel(city: "Amsterdam"), WeatherViewViewModel(city: "Missouri")]

func appendLocation(location: WeatherViewViewModel) {
    self.weatherVM.append(location)
}
}
```

'''

Models(not all since there are a lot)

WeatherResponse

'''

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct WeatherResponse: Codable {
var timezone = ""
var current: WeatherSubClass
var hourly: [Weather]
var daily: [DailyWeather]

static func empty() -> WeatherResponse {
    return WeatherResponse(timezone: "", current: WeatherSubClass(), hourly: [Weather](repeating: Weather(), count: 23), daily: [DailyWeather](repeating: DailyWeather(), count: 8))
}
}
```

'''

Weather(weathersubclass is also in here but it is mainly for getting sunrise and sunset data)

'''

```
import Foundation

class Weather: Codable, Identifiable {
var dt: Int
var temp: Double
var feels_like: Double
var pressure: Int
var humidity: Int
var dew_point: Double
var clouds: Int
var wind_speed: Double
var wind_deg: Int
var weather: [WeatherDetail]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case dt
    case temp
    case feels_like
    case pressure
    case humidity
    case dew_point
    case clouds
    case wind_speed
    case wind_deg
    case weather
}

init() {
    dt = 0
    temp = 0.0
    feels_like = 0.0
    pressure = 0
    humidity = 0
    dew_point = 0.0
    clouds = 0
    wind_speed = 0.0
    wind_deg = 0
    weather = []
}
}

extension Weather {
var id: UUID {
    return UUID()
}
}

class WeatherSubClass: Weather {
var sunrise: Int
var sunset: Int

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case sunrise
    case sunset
}

override init() {
    self.sunrise = 0
    self.sunset = 0
    super.init()
}

required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.sunrise = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .sunrise)
    self.sunset = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .sunset)
    try super.init(from: decoder)
}
}
```

'''

Updated WeatherViewModel(was originally WeatherViewViewModel)

'''

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

final class WeatherViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var weather = WeatherResponse.empty()
@Published var timeZone = WeatherResponse.empty().timezone
@Published var city: String {
    didSet {
        getLocation()
    }
}
@Published var weatherLocations: [WeatherViewModel] = [WeatherViewModel(city: "Phoenix"), WeatherViewModel(city: "Amsterdam"), WeatherViewModel(city: "Missouri")]

func appendLocation(location: WeatherViewModel) {
    weatherLocations.append(location)
}

private lazy var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .full
    return formatter
}()
```

'''

Comment: `@State` should never apear in your viewmodel. Only in views.

Comment: A few observations:
 I suggest you read-up on how to use `@EnvironmentObject` to pass your
 `@StateObject` around, it's easier that way.

There is no need for a separate `MultiLocationViewModel()`.
Re-structure your code to use just the `@StateObject var weatherVM = WeatherViewViewModel(city: "")`.
 
You would be better with `class Weather: Codable, Identifiable { let id = UUID() ....}`
 than your current computed (id) property that gives you a different value every time you use it. And as mentioned, do not use `@State var timeZone...` in your `WeatherViewViewModel`.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I tried refactoring the code so that I only had the one WeatherViewModel but now I am getting what appears to be a runtime error I think which is "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16acc3ff8)" which I get in a lot of places. I put the code for the updated WeatherViewModel(just the beginning since that is where I made the changes) at the end of the initial question. Also anywhere where I had multiWeatherViewModel.weatherVM I just replaced with the weatherVM.weatherLocations array and then I commented out all the times I initialized multiWeatherVM variable.

Comment: in your `WeatherViewModel` you have infinite recursion with `@Published var weatherLocations: [WeatherViewModel] `.
Do not nest `ObservableObject` it gives a lot of troubles. There is just too much `stuff` in your code for me to see what is going on.
If you are using `OpenWeather One Call API`, you may be interested in my library on github: https://github.com/workingDog/OWOneCall  and the example app at: https://github.com/workingDog/YAWA